# Strange issue in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

ok so this is very strange (well is to me), everything in my master branch works fine, I then created a new branch called twitter to conduct some twitter feed implementation. I have done this and was working yesterday on my linux machine.. I have pulled the branch today in a windows environment but when i load the app i now get the regular Sinatra 404 Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty.

This is my profile.rb file

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default)
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require './config/config.rb' if File.exists?('./config/config.rb')
require 'sinatra/jsonp'
require 'twitter'
require 'sinatra/static_assets'


class Profile < Sinatra::Base

helpers Sinatra::Jsonp
enable :json_pretty
register Sinatra::StaticAssets

@@twitter_client = Twitter::Client.new(
:consumer_key       => ENV["CONSUMER_KEY"],
:consumer_secret    => ENV["CONSUMER_SECRET"],
:oauth_token        => ENV["OAUTH_TOKEN"],
:oauth_token_secret => ENV["OAUTH_SECRET"],
)


get '/' do
 erb :index
end


get '/feed' do
 jsonp @@twitter_client.user_timeline('richl14').map(&:attrs)
end


end
```

Config.ru

```
  require './profile'

  run Profile
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what i need to be looking at to solve this? Can anyone speak from experience with this?

Thanks

Comment: How are you running it? If you use `ruby profile.rb` rather than `rackup` you’ll likely see 404s, since that will launch `Sinatra::Application` which doesn’t have any routes added.

Comment: yes thats what im doing, ruby profile.rb, so i should use rackup?

Comment: yes rackup works, thanks. mark as answer if you like, with maybe an explanation on the two ways you mentioned ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the classic Sinatra style you use `require 'sinatra'` and then add routes to the top level. These routes get added to the `Sinatra::Application`. When you directly run this file, e.g. with `ruby my_app.rb`, Sinatra runs a built in web server, which will serve the `Sinatra::Application` app.

When you use the modular style, you use `require 'sinatra/base'`, and then add routes to your `Sinatra::Base` subclass. In this case directly executing the file doesn’t start the built in server.

In your case you are using the modular style, but have used `require 'sinatra'`. You create your `Profile` app, but when you run the file directly Sinatra launches the built in server and serves the `Sinatra::Application` app. Since you haven’t added any routes to this (they’ve all been added to `Profile`) it runs but all requests return 404.

One way to get your app to launch you is to use `rackup`. This will launch the `Profile` app that you have explicitly set in your `config.ru`. (Explicitly starting your webserver will also work, e.g. using `thin start`).

Another possibility would be to add a line like this to the end of your `Profile` class:

```
run! if app_file == $0
```

This tells Sinatra to start the build in server running the `Profile` app if the file is the same as the Ruby file being executed, in a similar way to how the classic style app is launched. If you use this method you should change `require 'sinatra'` to `require 'sinatra/base'` otherwise you will get *two* servers launched, one after the other (in fact you should probably make that change anyway).

See the [Sinatra docs for more info about the difference between classic and modular style](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps).

Comment: That link at the bottom might not work correctly – SO is escaping the `::` in the anchor where I don’t think it should. Look for the section titled _“Sinatra::Base - Middleware, Libraries, and Modular Apps”_.